# How to center image gallery with text in Shopify without making the images smaller (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, shopify

I am trying to center my image gallery without decreasing the size of the images. I tried to work with some of the solutions in similar questions but they require making the images super small. Is there a way to keep the size of my images, have my images side by side, and just center the whole thing? :D Thanks so much in advance!

Here is my code:

```html
<style>

div.gallery {
margin: 5px;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
float: left;
text-align: center;
width: 330px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
border: 0px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

div.desc {
padding: 9px;
text-align: center;
display: block; 
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
<div class="gallery">
<a target="_blank" href="img.jpg">
</a><a target="_blank" href="img.jpg"><img src="img.jpg" alt="Select Your Flavors" width="600" height="400">
</a>
<div class="desc"><h3>Choose Your Flavors</h3></div>
<div class="desc">
<p>Text</p>
<div class="center-section"><a class="btn button" href="https://completeats.myshopify.com/collections/shop">Find Your Box</a></div>
</div>
<p></p>
</div>


<div class="gallery">
<a target="_blank" href="img.jpg">
</a><a target="_blank" href="img.jpg"><img src="img" alt="Get Your Box" width="600" height="400">
</a>
<div class="desc"><h3>Get Your Box</h3></div>
<div class="center-section">
<a class="btn button" href="https://completeats.myshopify.com/collections/shop">Find Your Box</a><p></p>
</div>
</div>
<p></p>
</div>


<div class="gallery">
<a target="_blank" href="img.jpg">
</a><a target="_blank" href="img.jpg"><img src="img" width="600" height="400">
</a>
<div class="desc"><h3>text</h3></div>
<div class="center-section"><a class="btn button" href="">Shop Now</a></div>
</div>
<p></p>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i add `"cover"` your `"gallery"` div with `"gallery-wrapper"` class and add css for center image align.

```css
.gallery-wrapper{
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<style>
div.gallery {
margin: 5px;
border: 0px solid #ccc;
float: left;
text-align: center;
width: 330px;
}
div.gallery:hover {
border: 0px solid #777;
}
div.gallery img {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
div.desc {
padding: 9px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
<div class="gallery-wrapper">   
    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="img.jpg">
            </a><a target="_blank" href="img.jpg"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" alt="Select Your Flavors" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc"><h3>Choose Your Flavors</h3></div>
        <div class="desc">
            <p>Text</p>
            <div class="center-section"><a class="btn button" href="https://completeats.myshopify.com/collections/shop">Find Your Box</a></div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <a target="_blank" href="img.jpg">
            </a><a target="_blank" href="img.jpg"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" alt="Get Your Box" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc"><h3>Get Your Box</h3></div>
        <div class="center-section">
            <a class="btn button" href="https://completeats.myshopify.com/collections/shop">Find Your Box</a><p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img.jpg">
        </a><a target="_blank" href="img.jpg"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" width="600" height="400">
        </a>
        <div class="desc"><h3>text</h3></div>
        <div class="center-section"><a class="btn button" href="">Shop Now</a></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Satish. However, this does not seem to solve my problem. Maybe I didn't describe it well enough. I am trying to get the gallery in the top center on a page on my website. I tried the gallery-wrapper but it didn't change.

Comment: You need to post a working example or URL of the page where it currently.

Comment: @Onkar I linked it above

Comment: @JudithPrugger sorry to say but the link returns 404

Answer (score 0):

like this :https://i.ibb.co/pzz0MxF/846c4b24-6934-4447-82c1-a25b11ea581c.png

**Note:** always use class name as section name like "club-works" for good css under standing

You have to add css in this class

```
.custom-html .custom-html__code {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you! I spent way to much time finding out what the problem is!! :D